# Juniper SRX firewall routing configuration

Tags: configuration, routes, firewall, juniper

I have a question about Juniper SRX firewall configuration,
Running 11.4R7

My question is about routing table used while processing traffic passing through the firewall,
I have routing configuration part of the routing-instances definition, and it looks like this :

```
set routing-instances Main-VR instance-type virtual-router
set routing-instances Main-VR interface reth0.0
set routing-instances Main-VR routing-options static route 10.80.90.0/27 next-hop 10.80.90.40
```

Then i could find another routing definition as

```
 routing-options    static route 10.62.170.190/32 next-hop 10.80.93.1
 routing-options    static route 10.62.170.0/24 next-hop 10.80.93.1
 routing-options    static route 10.61.105.0/26 next-hop 10.80.93.1
 routing-options    static route 10.66.65.103/32 next-hop 10.80.93.1
```

What’s the difference between the two definitions?
Are both active, i mean checked while traffic processing taking place?
Or I could remove one of them

Answer (score 1):

Static routes defined under `set routing-options` are for Global Routing Table and the ones defined under `set routing-instances Main-VR routing-options` are for the Virtual Router(Main VR).

Answer (score 0):

`routing-options static route 10.62.170.190/32 next-hop 10.80.93.1` could be removed, as `routing-options static route 10.62.170.0/24 next-hop 10.80.93.1` already contains the `10.62.170.190/32` destination.

---

The rest would need to stay as they are destinations to individual networks or destinations. As a first step suggestion I would deactivate route `10.62.170.190/32 next-hop 10.80.93.1`, then test for connectivity to your end point destination before finally removing the item from your configuration.